# Secure HTTP Streaming Plugin with FlowPlayer always says "Stream Not Found"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, flowplayer

I think I have everything configured correctly, but I can not stream any video with flowplayer and [this plugin](http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/secure-http.html) actived.

The structure of the files is:

```
index.php
sectimestamp.php
secure/
--.htaccess
--video.mp4 <-- Mi video (2.4 MB)
--video.php
flowplayer/
--flowplayer-3.2.18.swf
--flowplayer.controls-3.2.16.swf
--flowplayer.securestreaming-3.2.9.swf
```

(All files and dirs set with 755 permission)

In index.php:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- A minimal Flowplayer setup to get you started -->


  <!-- 
    include flowplayer JavaScript file that does  
    Flash embedding and provides the Flowplayer API.
  -->
  <!-- flowplayer depends on jQuery 1.7.1+ (for now) -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $f("player", "flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
        plugins: {
          secure: {
            url: "flowplayer/flowplayer.securestreaming-3.2.9.swf",
            timestampUrl: "sectimestamp.php"
          }
        },
        clip: {
          baseUrl: "secure",
          url: "video.mp4",
          autoPlay: false,
          urlResolvers: "secure",
          scaling: "fit",
        }
      });
    });
  </script>  


</head><body>

<div id="player"></div>

</body></html>
```

sectimestamp.php:

```
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

video.php:

```
<?php
$hash = $_GET['h'];
$streamname = $_GET['v'];
$timestamp = $_GET['t'];
$current = time();
$token = 'sn983pjcnhupclavsnda';
$checkhash = md5($token . '/' . $streamname . $timestamp);

if (($current - $timestamp) <= 2 && ($checkhash == $hash)) {
  $fsize = filesize($streamname);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $streamname . '"');
  if (strrchr($streamname, '.') == '.mp4') {
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
  } else {
    header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');
  }
  header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);
  session_cache_limiter('nocache');
  header('Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
  header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  $file = fopen($streamname, 'rb');
  print(fread($file, $fsize));
  fclose($file);
  exit;
} else {
  header('Location: /secure');
}
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /secure

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ video.php?h=$1&t=$2&v=$3

RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+\.(flv|mp4)$ - [F]
```

Mod Rewrite is enabled in apache.

Server info:

PHP Version 5.6.0-1
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

[Test URL](http://muradevelopment.com/flowdev)

What is my problem? Thanks in advance.

Ps. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

```
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /FULLPATH/video.php?h=$1&t=$2&v=$3
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.